# Python: requests.post not posting

Tags: python, json, firebase, python-requests

I'm trying to post a json string to Google Firebase.

The same command works without hickups using curl, but if I do that using Python, there's no data in the DB.

Here's the code:

```
postdata = {"pm10": pm10, "pm2.5": pm25, "lat": gps_data.get('latitude'), "lon": gps_data.get('longitude'), "alt": gps_data.get('speed'), "spd": gps_data.get('altitude2'), "satt": gps_data.get('satellites')}

logging.info(args.url)
logging.info(postdata)


r = requests.post(args.url, data=postdata, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

logging.debug(r)
```

I call the script using:

> python l.py -u http://blabla.firebaseio.com/test1.json

The output is:

```
INFO:Serial device initialized
INFO:Posting to http://blabla.firebaseio.com/test1.json
INFO:http://blabla.firebaseio.com/test1.json
INFO:{'satt': 10, 'pm10': 30, 'lon': XX.XXXXX, 'pm2.5': 27, 'lat': YY.YYYYY, 'alt': 0.037, 'spd': 336.8}
INFO:PM 10: 30
INFO:PM 2.5: 27
INFO:Latitude: XX.XXXX
INFO:longitude: YY.YYYYY
```

But when I open the DB, no data.

Using curl with the same parameters works.

Update:

Logging debug provides this as info:

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): blabla.firebaseio.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://blabla.firebaseio.com:80 "POST /test1.json HTTP/1.1" 404 1571
DEBUG:root:<Response [404]>
```

Comment: Looks like your `logging.debug(r)` line isn't printing, can you set your log level to `DEBUG` or otherwise show us what the `r` object has for the following values? `r.status_code` and `r.text`?

Comment: Your data got invalid `type`, before save data `json.dumps(your_data)`(which method on use : table/Whole_data_as_string?)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I set the log level to debug?

Comment: Ok, found it, this is the output: DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): blabla.firebaseio.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://blabla.firebaseio.com:80 "POST /test1.json HTTP/1.1" 404 1571
DEBUG:root:<Response [404]>

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the issue was with one of the variables being passed as json contained an invalid char.

The value was pm2.5, so I just renamed it to pm25.

The key is not to have any chars such as . - or something of the sort.

After that it started working.